# Import huge XML data set into MongoDB while parsing data

Tags: python, performance, parsing, xml, mongodb

I am currently working with the [Stack Exchange Data Dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) - to be more precise - with the dumped `Posts.xml` data set from Stack Overflow.

**What am I trying to achieve?**
I want to read the whole data set and import each row (a post on Stack Overflow) as a document into an MongoDB database.

**What am I doing right now?**
I am using the `iterparse()` function from `lxml` to iterate over each row, without building a DOM. Every row contains attributes which hold the actual data. As every attribute is a String, I need to parse some attributes into Integers, Dates and Lists. This is done by the `attrib_to_dict()` function. The resulting Dictionary is simply inserted into the database collection.

**What is the problem?**
The parsing of the attributes is quite slow. The whole process took about two hours on my machine. By using the `multiprocessing` module I was able to speed up the process substantially. The iteration over the whole data set without doing anything is quite fast.

```py
# main.py
from lxml import etree as et
from tqdm import tqdm
import multiprocessing as mp
import pymongo

from constants import POSTS_SIZE
from posts import attrib_to_dict

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

# database
stackoverflow = client["stackoverflow"]
# collection
posts = stackoverflow["posts"]

def work(elem):
    try:
        # turn the String back into an element, pass attributes to parsing function
        posts.insert_one(attrib_to_dict(et.fromstring(elem).attrib))
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        # skip element
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    # progress bar
    pbar = tqdm(total=POSTS_SIZE)
    def update(*args):
        # add one to total processed elements
        pbar.update(1)
    try:
        for event, elem in et.iterparse("Posts.xml", tag="row"):
            # pass element as a String to the worker
            # passing the attribute object directly did not seem to work
            pool.apply_async(work, args=(et.tostring(elem),), callback=update) 
            elem.clear()
        pool.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
    finally:
        pbar.close()
        pool.join()
```

```py
# posts.py
from datetime import datetime as dt

def attrib_to_dict(attrib):
    result = {}

    result["_id"] = int(attrib.get("Id"))

    result["PostTypeId"] = int(attrib.get("PostTypeId"))

    # nullable attributes
    acceptedAnswerId = attrib.get("AcceptedAnswerId")
    if acceptedAnswerId: result["AcceptedAnswerId"] = int(acceptedAnswerId)

    result["CreationDate"] = dt.fromisoformat(attrib.get("CreationDate"))

    # about 10 more conversions ...

    tags = attrib.get("Tags")
    # "<python><mongodb>" -> ["python", "mongodb"]
    if tags: result["Tags"] = [tag[:-1] for tag in tags.split("<")[1:]]

    return result
```

Some performance metrics:

```
no inserts, no parsing, passing None to worker: 13427.88 items/s
no inserts, no parsing, passing et.tostring(elem) to worker: 10177.07 items/s
no inserts, parsing, passing et.tostring(elem) to worker: 9637.41 items/s
inserts, parsing, passing et.tostring(elem) to worker: 7185.15 items/s
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to Code Review! Here we like to have as much of the code as possible. You might get better reviews if you also include the skipped conversions, there might be some structure there that helps simplifying it. You might also want to mention the size of the XML file (14.6GB in 7z format). Have you tried profiling your code to see which part exactly is the slowest? Maybe it is the inserting rows one at a time into the DB and not the parsing?

Comment: Thanks for your comment and interest! The skipped conversions are structurally build like the ones posted, but simply with other attribute names, which is why I have skipped them. I included all types of conversions that I used. I added some performance metrics to show the processing speed with and without parsing, etc.
It seems that the insertion into the database is slowing down the process more than the parsing itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since inserting into the DB takes a non-negligible amount of time, you should try to use `insert_many`, instead of `insert_one`. If you used a single thread this would be easy, just chunk your file and insert a whole chunk. Since you are using multiprocessing, this is a bit more complicated, but it should still be doable

(untested code)

```
from itertools import islice
import pymongo
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
import et


def chunks(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    while (chunk := tuple(islice(it, n))):  # Python 3.8+
        yield chunk

def work(chunk):
    try:
        posts.insert_many([attrib_to_dict(elem.attrib) for _, elem in chunk],
                          ordered=False)
    except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError:
        # skip element
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    # progress bar
    pbar = tqdm(total=POSTS_SIZE)
    n = 100
    try:
        for chunk in chunks(et.iterparse("Posts.xml", tag="row"), n):
            pool.apply_async(work, args=(chunk,),
                             callback=lambda: pbar.update(len(chunk)))
        pool.close()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pool.terminate()
    finally:
        pbar.close()
        pool.join()
```

Here I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319442/4042267) to ignore duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm struggling with the multiprocessing implementation because I'm not able to clear the current element correctly with `elem.clear()` to free memory.

I used your chunk based approach with a single thread instead which already resulted in a processing speed of 15596.80 items/s. Maybe updating the progress bar every item also slowed the process down, I am updating it for every chunk now instead.